# How to Add Slide Down and Up Function to HTML Select Element

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can you please take a look at this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/4yhy7/2/) and let me know how I can add slide Up and Down for select element using jquery?

Here is the code I have:

```
<select id="sl">
    <option value="volvo">Select From The List ... </option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sl").click(function () {
        $("option").slideDown();
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need slide down functionality for a select list by nature of select list you can see the list items on clicking on it. Can you explain your requirement more.

Comment: In short, you cant--not to a select element. Its behavior is governed by the browser.

Comment: Hi Ted, thanks but have you seen this: http://patrickkunka.github.io/easydropdown/ ? so it is possible to do it

Comment: @Behseini So, why don't you use it?

Comment: @Pavlo, just wondering how I can do it on my own!

Comment: @Vinay Kumar.o, Hi and thanks for reply, the reason which I have to use the slide up and down is I am using the Select element inside an accordion panel and I have to set the size of panel to be increased base on the select options opens and close. Now if I want to keep the classic mood of select the panel also opens so fast!

Comment: @Behseini Look at the code for the other, it'll help you along with your own version

Comment: @Behseini you would need to "hide" the select list you have or remove it after transforming it into some other html elements.. the item in the list is Not a select element.. its been replaced by Div's... have you seen the chosen plugin before? http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ Its a nice transformation of a selet but not sure if it has the slide up / down..